# How to hide content against other users

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a registration/login system created in spring. It is based on roles. I have also entity Item. When I register a user then I am able to go on jsp page where I can create an item. I have a page that displays all items ( id, name, etc. ) my question is how can I connect this item entity with user? When I register a user it has an id of course i.e. 1 and when I create an item on him I would like to have this item visible only for him. How the relationship should looks like? User can have many items and items can have many users. But when I do a ManyToMany relationship the problem still appears. Any ideas how to hide other entities if they are not created on specific user? Any ideas, thanks for help.

Comment: Well, you'd need the many-to-many relation between items and users but you also need to filter on that in order to restrict access based on that relation.

Comment: What problem do you face while implementing many2many relationship? Also, if a logged in user creates an entity, how will you create the entities relation with other user?

Comment: @Thomas could you please create a simple example that shows it, because I am not sure that I understand it correctly.

Comment: @ManishBansal I would like to register a user, then go to a page when I can create an item, and see this item only as this logged user. When I register a different user I should be not able to see the entity created previously.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you select the items but one way would be to join the users and filtering on elements that match the current user's id (e.g. using a with-expression). Alternatively you could use one of Hibernate's collection expressions or a subquery.